# Troubleshooting broken washing machine

Tags: repair, drain, washing-machine, pump, hose

I'm trying to fix a broken washing machine and any advice, hints, tips would be greatly appreciated. It is a Proline PFL 106F.

It switches on, but won't start when you select any of the cycles. It beeps. I've checked the manual and the number of beeps doesn't really correspond to anything meaningful in the troubleshooting section. So I started by cleaning out the drainage filter, which made no difference. Then I pulled out the washing machine and verified that it is indeed receiving a supply of cold water, which is it. I checked the drainage hose for any obvious obstructions, and there are none I can see.

So next I opened it up. I can see no obvious signs of problems with any of the electrics, no burnt out capacitors or wire connectors that have worked themselves loose. The drum and motor all appear in decent condition. The belt running the drum seems to be fine, decent tension, no damage.

Next I thought it best to try and inspect the drainage system to see whether there was any blockage. I thought to tackle this next since when the cycle is selected it doesn't get to the stage where the washing machine does a quick drain before the cycle starts, like it normally does.

At that point I'd like to be a bit more confident that I'm on the right track trying to access the drainage system. Does that sound reasonable? Which part is the best to inspect?

Furthermore, if I procede with disconnecting the drain pump, etc, there are a number of hose clamps, which you can see in the photos. I believe that these are removed by applying a bit of pressure with some pliers. But I'm just wondering whether if I remove them, whether I'll have to buy new ones, or whether I can re-use the original ones. I'm guessing by squeezing them open, they'll lose some of their torque and might not seal the hose adequately. What do you think?

Any suggestions on all of that very welcome!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check the control board? Sounds more like a lose connection than a drainage problem.

Comment: Hose clamps can usually be reused, but they are inexpensive and replacing with new are not a bad idea.

Comment: Is the door closing and latching correctly?

Comment: That's gotta be the cleanest, non working washer I've ever seen.

Comment: @JACK - I had a look over it, but I'll go through each connection one by one. It is indeed very clean! :-)

Comment: @SolarMike - yes it appears to closing and latching correctly.

Comment: @crip659 - Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: That's good, as the doors tend to have a switch associated with them to stop the machine running / filling with the door not closed correctly.

Comment: Doubt my stuff would look that clean after a good hour of cleaning.

Comment: @crip659 There was no washing of the washing machine :-)

Comment: @SolarMike See what you're getting at, it seems securely shutting, but I'm guessing I can't get at the sensor or trigger that determines if the door is closed without going a step further and removing more panels, parts to access it.

Comment: So, chase the wires - that will tell you.

Comment: [Instruction manual](https://www.manua.ls/proline/pfl-106f/manual?p=18) -- English section begins with page 18.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the suggestions. The washing machine is now working again, but not 100% why.

I disconnected the drain pump and the impeller wasn't damaged. Although I did find a small piece of plastic from a shirt collar insert in one of the inlets for the drain pump. I'm not 100% that was the cause since it didn't appear to be creating an obstruction. Plus, the shirt it came from hasn't been washed for a while, so doesn't appear to be something new that stopped it from working, however, can't be sure.

I disconnected the cold water inlet and checked the connection with the soap dispenser.

I removed the door and reattached it, trying my best to check the connection with the attached sensor to make sure it hadn't worked itself loose.

I checked all the wires and connections to the control board, making sure they were all properly connected.

After all of this I didn't think I really I'd done anything to solve the problem, so reassembled it, not wanting to spend another day surrounded by washing machine parts. And lo and behold the machine started.

For the first test wash the programme selector wouldn't change from Rapid wash, nor would it let me change the temperature. It was beeping twice too, but did start a wash. For the second wash, after turning it off and on, it indeed let me alter the programme and change the temperature. Plus, the beeps had stopped.

So that leads me to suspect maybe the problem is in fact the control board. Or else the plastic did create an obstruction to the drain pump. Or as my wife said, 'it just needed a jiggle', the act of dismantling it and putting it back together solved the problem! :-)

Anyway, appreciate the support all.